# Realistic firework simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shaders

I wanted to create a firework simulation but the blast particles look weird as if they are in a trail. I wanted to know what are the particle's settings for an instant explosion like in real fireworks.

Render Preview:

[image]

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on yt for that….

Comment: Did you enter a _Randomize_ velocity for the particles or are you just using _Normal_ velocity? And does the emitter have a small amount of faces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few pointers in addition to those made in the comments:

- Add some **Damping**, **Drag** and maybe even **Brownian** to the physics to make the particles slow down in mid-air. The sparks from a firework are very light and slow down quickly when travelling through the air. This can be found in the **Physics** panel.
- Add some glow to those particles. In Eevee this can be achieved with the **Bloom** setting, but in Cycles (and I can see that's what you're using,) you'll need to add a Fog Glow (in the **Glare** node) in the compositor. It looks like you've already added a lens flare so you're almost there already.
- Maybe use [Forces like Wind or Noise](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPkZXawKT2AhWIN8AKHUS3B6oQwqsBegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DTPxb60TjNcw&usg=AOvVaw0ZaFA9tFtoVjaUQNerZ2cv) to add a little extra granular motion to the particles. At the moment they travel linearly and die. On that note,
- Randomise the lifespan a little more. They all seem to die within the space of about 3 frames which, in my opinion, is a bit too uniform.

This is all for just the one firework you've shown us. It'd be cool to see a variety of fireworks with different effects going on too!